# Automatic Redirection to previously requested page,once authentication is successful in Servlet and JSP

Tags: authentication, servlets, redirect

I have an application developed in Servlets and JSPs.
But here is my issue:

Without logging in I don't want any JSP to be rendered. When I request a particular URL(some JSP) my code should authenticate it and if fails it should be redirected to login page and once login is successful then previously requested page should be automatically redirected.

Which usually happens in most of the websites.
How do we achieve this Servlets and JSPs.

Thank you and Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the original request url as a parameter to your redirect url and once the redirect action is complete on the server side (after authentication), retrieve the url from the request param and redirect or forward to it.

```
Original request
-----------------

if(!authenticated){
   response.sendRedirect("/authURL?originalURL=somepath");
}

Authentication Request
---------------------

if(authenticationSuccessful){
    String originalURL = request.getParam("originalURL");
    if(originalURL != null){
        response.sendRedirect("/originalURL");
    }
}
```

Another way is to set a cookie with the redirect. The cookie value can contain the original url.